# PHP regex use same letter

Tags: php, regex, tags

Im trying to do a regex where I can find all html tags, but for each one, each opening and closing tag must be the same. Heres what I mean: (Yes I only want max 3 letters)

```
preg_match_all("/\<[a-z]{1,3}\>(.*?)\<\/[a-z]{1,3}\>/", $string, $matches);
```

Where the 2 `[a-z]{1,3}` are, I want those to be the same, so it doesn't match `<b>` with `<\i>`, etc. Thanks... let me know if you need further explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Use [PHP Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) instead.

Comment: Im not really parsing HTML, its just the closest example and easiest explanation to show what Im trying to do..

Comment: So you're parsing XML? :P  Sorry, whenever I see `regex` and HTML I laugh.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you're parsing HTML/XML or if you're checking for specific closing-tags. HTML and Regex go together like gasoline and milk. i.e., not recommended. :)

Comment: @David: If it's so much *like* HTML, could you just use an *ML parser anyways?

Answer (score 1):

you really shouldn't be parsing *ml with regex because of problems with nested elements, but if this is any help:

```
preg_match_all("/<([a-z]{1,3})>(.*?)<\/\1>/", $string, $matches);
```

Comment: Be aware that this won't handle tags that are enclosed in the same kind of tag.  For example, given `<foo><foo></foo></foo>`, it will match `<foo><foo></foo>`.

Answer (score 0):

As Vivin Paliath said plus you can try to use PHP5's DomDocument with XPath

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php